# Developing app in laravel 5.1 having reflection error, i am using Wamp server URL: http://localhost/laravel/public/.

Tags: php, laravel

I  am migrating one table to database

C:\wamp\www\laravel>php artisan migrate

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Co
nsole\Kernel does not exist' in C:\wamp\www\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src
\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 736
ReflectionException: Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist in C:\wamp\www\lara
vel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 736
Call Stack:
0.0010     123768   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\laravel\artisan:0
0.0380    1075752   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() C:\wamp\www
\laravel\artisan:31
0.0380    1075832   3. Illuminate\Container\Container->make() C:\wamp\www\la
ravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:674
0.0380    1075832   4. Illuminate\Container\Container->build() C:\wamp\www\l
aravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:626
0.0380    1075832   5. Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\
{closure}() C:\wamp\www\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Containe
r\Container.php:733
0.0380    1075880   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() C:\wamp\www
\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:216
0.0380    1075880   7. Illuminate\Container\Container->make() C:\wamp\www\la
ravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:674
0.0380    1075896   8. Illuminate\Container\Container->build() C:\wamp\www\l
aravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:626
0.0380    1076072   9. ReflectionClass->__construct() C:\wamp\www\laravel\ve
ndor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:736
```

I am new to laravel and this is demo setup for one project and getting confuse with these errors.

Comment: Did you `composer update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the error on existing projects. Make sure the bindings in bootstrap/app.php are correct and run composer dump-autoload to clear out any lingering issues.